# How to use a list of rules as a data set

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a file of models that I have saved that I want to be able to call in another program to be solved with `NDSolve`. Can I use `Cases` to select each model based upon the m# tag given in the model list? I've tried to avail the following.

```
test = {
    {
     m1-> 
     {
      {ul'[t]==k1p*s*(1-ul[t])/(km1+(1-ul[t]))-k2p*ul[t]/(km2+ul[t])-         
       k5p*ul[t]*um[t]/(km5+ul[t])},
      {um'[t]==k3p*uc[t]*(1-um[t])/(km3+(1-um[t]))-k4p*um[t]/(km4+um[t])},
      {uc'[t]==k6p*ul[t]*(1-uc[t])/(km6+(1-uc[t]))-k7p*uc[t]/(km7+uc[t])}
     },
      {ul[0]==0.,um[0]==0.,uc[0]==0.0},
      {s, k1p, km1, k2p, km2, k5p, km5, k3p, km3, k4p, km4, k6p, km6, k7p, km7}
    },
    {
     m2-> 
      {
       {ul'[t]==k1p*s*(1-ul[t])/(km1+(1-ul[t]))-k2p*ul[t]/(km2+ul[t])-
        k5p*um[t]*ul[t]/(km5+ul[t])},
       {um'[t]==k3p*ul[t]*(1-um[t])/(km3+(1-um[t]))-k4p*um[t]/(km4+um[t])}
      },
       {ul[0]==0.,um[0]==0.},
       {s, k1p, km1, k2p, km2, k5p, km5, k3p, km3, k4p, km4}
      }
   }

openModel[modelName_] := Cases[test, modelName]  

openModel[m1]
```

Comment: Are you using Mathematica 10? If so, I have an very straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Please take a look at existing answers before editing the question. My answer diverged from the variable you introduced afterwards: You used "test", I used "models".

I adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jinxed. Your answer was fine even before you edited it. I don't think anyone would have been confused by the difference in identifier; but I apologize for not paying more attention to your answer and using `models`.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Thanks for the positive review!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution for *Mathematica* before version 10

You can use the following function to achieve your goal:

```
openModel[modelName_] := 
 Cases[test, Rule[key_, res__] :> res /; key == modelName, 2]
```

e.g.: `openModel[m2]` will return

```
{{{Derivative[1][ul][t] == (k1p s (1 - ul[t]))/(1 + km1 - ul[t]) - (
 k2p ul[t])/(km2 + ul[t]) - (k5p ul[t] um[t])/(
 km5 + ul[t])}, {Derivative[1][um][t] == (k3p ul[t] (1 - um[t]))/(
 1 + km3 - um[t]) - (k4p um[t])/(km4 + um[t])}}}
```

### Solution for *Mathematica* 10

You can make use of associations in *Mathematica* 10 by changing your model definition according to this one (i.e.: make use of `Association`):

```
test = <|
  m1 -> {{{ul'[t] == 
       k1p*s*(1 - ul[t])/(km1 + (1 - ul[t])) - 
        k2p*ul[t]/(km2 + ul[t]) - 
        k5p*ul[t]*um[t]/(km5 + ul[t])}, {um'[t] == 
       k3p*uc[t]*(1 - um[t])/(km3 + (1 - um[t])) - 
        k4p*um[t]/(km4 + um[t])}, {uc'[t] == 
       k6p*ul[t]*(1 - uc[t])/(km6 + (1 - uc[t])) - 
        k7p*uc[t]/(km7 + uc[t])}}, {ul[0] == 0., um[0] == 0., 
     uc[0] == 0.0}, {s, k1p, km1, k2p, km2, k5p, km5, k3p, km3, k4p, 
     km4, k6p, km6, k7p, km7}}, 
  m2 -> {{{ul'[t] == 
       k1p*s*(1 - ul[t])/(km1 + (1 - ul[t])) - 
        k2p*ul[t]/(km2 + ul[t]) - 
        k5p*um[t]*ul[t]/(km5 + ul[t])}, {um'[t] == 
       k3p*ul[t]*(1 - um[t])/(km3 + (1 - um[t])) - 
        k4p*um[t]/(km4 + um[t])}}, {ul[0] == 0., um[0] == 0.}, {s, 
     k1p, km1, k2p, km2, k5p, km5, k3p, km3, k4p, km4}}
|>
```

Then, the `openModel`-method reduces to:

```
openModel[modelName_] := test[modelName]
```

yielding the same result as above.

I hope to have been of some help to you.

Comment: Unless you need numeric equivalence in the `modelName` parameter you can reduce the first function to `openModel[modelName_] := Cases[test, (modelName -> res_) :> res, 2]`

Comment: I've gone with the first iteration here, I would like to take advantage of the assoications method. Both answers from jinxed and mr. Wizard solve the problem. However Mathematica v.10 is so unstable with memory management that I've reverted back to v.9. So no use of Associations quite yet. Hopefully they'll fix those leaky memory issues soon :)

Comment: @tarhawk: Try disabling the Suggestion Bar. It has caused me some trouble already: (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71889/24763)